# Intellij remove keyboard shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using a mac with a Hungarian keyboard. When I want to write **>** sign with option+shift+x IntelliJ closes my tabs. I went through the keyboard shortcuts in IntelliJ but I couldn't find this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to *Preferences / Settings | Keymap | Main Menu | Tools | Tasks & Contexts | Clear Context* and remove/reassign the shortcut.